# JS question I got using async/sync/timings

Tags: javascript, node.js

I received a js interview question that I don't know how to solve, hopefully you guys could help me, so it goes like that:

A company made this code:
(note: `goo()` cannot return 0, both `foo` and `goo` return numbers)

```js
function calculate(x) {
    return foo(x) / goo(x, 0);
}
```

But then, they made better API and they moved their functions to be async, so they are getting callbacks,
So they implemented the same functionality but with callbacks:

```js
function calculateBetter(x, callback) {
    fooBetter(x, (result) => {
        gooBetter(x, 0, (result2) => {
            callback(result / result2);
        });
    });
}
```

The question: How this `calculateBetter` could be optimize to finish as quickly as possible?

Restriction: Use pure js, no need to use workers / promises.

Hints I got:

1. `fooBetter` and `gooBetter` are independently on each other.
2. A link to this [node js doc part](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick).

From what I've felt from the interviewer, the answer should include something related to how async/sync/timings deeply work in js, and the fact that since fooBetter and gooBetter are independetly, we might not fooBetter and only when I get the answer to use gooBetter.

Comment: Is there a declaration provide for fooBetter and gooBetter?

Comment: @PavlosKaralis Nope.

Comment: Since `fooBetter()` and `gooBetter()` are independent asynchronous operations, they can be run in parallel.  Promisify them, then use `Promise.all()` to know when both are done.  You may get the final result faster (depending upon what `fooBetter()` and `gooBetter()` actually do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the point the interviewer wants to hear is that, `gooBetter` is not called until `fooBetter` has finished. It would be faster, if `gooBetter` gets started even not when `fooBetter` has finished. One possible solution which - I have to admit - is not that clean, is to have a variable which is used to determine if both functions have already finished. That look like this:

```js
function calculateBetter(x, callback) {
    let fooResult;
    let gooResult;

    fooBetter(x, (result) => {
        fooResult = result;
        if (gooResult) {
            callback(fooResult / gooResult);
        }
    });
    gooBetter(x, 0, (result) => {
        gooResult = result;
        if (fooResult) {
            callback(fooResult / gooResult);
        }
    });
}
```

If you can use Promises this question would be simpler.

Comment: But there is one-main thread, so how would it actually faster than doing one after another if anyway only one of them is being executed?

Comment: Maybe the operations happen asynchronous and / or on multiple threads ... But yes u've got a point

Answer (score 1):

Well, calling a nonstandard callback based asynchronous function "better" is not very accurate. May I suggest to use some javascript features that are designed to deal with asynchronous code. I'm talking about Promises and async/await, like this:

```
function promisifyNonstandardValueFirst(fn) {
    return function _promisified(...args) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fn(...args, (value, error) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    resolve(value);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}


const fooBest = promisifyNonstandardValueFirst(fooBetter);
const gooBest = promisifyNonstandardValueFirst(gooBetter);

async function calculateBest(x) {
    const [value1, value2] = await Promise.all([fooBest(x), gooBest(x)]);
    return value1 / value2;
}
```

I hope they are not expecting you to roll your own callback based async toolkit for parallelism, [which has been done many times already](https://medium.com/velotio-perspectives/understanding-node-js-async-flows-parallel-serial-waterfall-and-queues-6f9c4badbc17) and is outdated anyway.